# android lollipop and socket.io not working together

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, android-5.0-lollipop, gottox

I have a simple chat application on nodejs with socket.io@0.9.16 module.`The chat app works fine with android 4.x`.But I tried on android 5.0.I got some errors. 
***errors on server log:***
[image: errors on server log]

> What is the relationship of this error with android version
>   differences?

This error may be releated to the json.I saw.There are experiencing problems with json in Android lollipop 5.0.Does anyone have experience with this issue?
**UPDATE:**
When I debug,I discovered that:

```
if (jsObj != null)
    socket.emit("bla", jsObj);
```

jsObj is not null.But I get the null jsobj on the server-side after emitted.Why??

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution.`JsonObject` doesn't work properly in the android lollipop(5.0).So I tried

```
CustomObject customObject=new CustomObject();//from my customObject.class
customObject.setValue(customValue);//setter from customObject.class
Gson gson=new Gson();
String json=gson.toJson(customObject);
```

instead of:

```
 JsonObject jsonObj=new JsonObject();
 jsonObj.addProperty("value",customValue);
```

and so worked properly.
I hope this solution helps you too.
Regards.